# The command "ng -v" displays an error on rxjs

Tags: angular

After issuing the following two statements to upgrade my cli:

```
npm upgrade -g @angular/cli
npm upgrade @angular/cli
```

Issuing `ng -v` gives this:

```
Angular CLI: 6.0.7
Node: 8.11.2
OS: darwin x64
Angular: 
... 

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.6.7
@angular-devkit/core         0.6.7
@angular-devkit/schematics   0.6.7
@schematics/angular          0.6.7
@schematics/update           0.6.7
rxjs                         <error>
```

So, `rxjs` lists error on Version, and then info about other plugins is cut short. **Is there a fix?**

Comment: try `npm install -g rxjs`

Comment: Yea thanks. I know I could do that later in the process, but wanted to make sure all is in order with the ng command.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the local `cli` is getting in the way. I uninstalled the local one with a `npm uninstall @angular/cli` and ran `ng -v` again. All good now.